# postgresql stored procedures vs server-side javascript functions

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures

In my application I receive json data in a post request that I store as raw json data in a table. I use postgresql (9.5) and node.js .

In this example, the data is an array of about 10 quiz questions experienced by a user, that looks like this:

```
[{"QuestionId":1, "score":1, "answerList":["1"], "startTime":"2015-12-14T11:26:54.505Z", "clickNb":1, "endTime":"2015-12-14T11:26:57.226Z"}, 
 {"QuestionId":2, "score":1, "answerList":["3", "2"], "startTime":"2015-12-14T11:27:54.505Z", "clickNb":1, "endTime":"2015-12-14T11:27:57.226Z"}]
```

I need to store (temporarily or permanently) several indicators computed by aggregating data from this json at quizz level, as I need these indicators to perform other procedures in my database.

As of now I was computing the indicators using javascript functions at the time of handling the post request and inserting the values in my table alongside the raw json data. I'm wondering if it wouldn't be more performant to have the calculation performed by a stored trigger function in my postgresql db (knowing that the sql function would need to retrieve the data from inside the json raw data).

I have read other posts on this topic, but it was asked many years ago and not with node.js, so I thought people might have some new insight on the pros and cons of using sql stored procedures vs server-side javascript functions.

edit: I should probably have mentioned that most of my application's logic already mostly lies in postgresql stored procedures and views.

Comment: I tend to put logic where it needs to be and view the database as a separate application whose API just happens to be SQL. If the logic is required for data consistency and integrity then it should be inside the database because maintaining the data is the database's job. BTW, there is PL/v8 for PostgreSQL so you can write triggers and procedures in JavaScript if you're worried about dealing with too many languages.

Comment: cool, I didn't know about PL/v8

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would not use that approach due to the risk of getting the triggers out of sync with the code. In general, the single responsibility principle should be the guide: DB to store data and code to manipulate it. Unless you have a really pressing business need to break this pattern, I'd advise against it.

Do you have a migration that will recreate the triggers if you wipe the DB and start from scratch? Will you or a coworker not realise they are there at a later point when reading the app code and wonder what is going on? If there is a standardised way to manage the triggers where the configuration will be stored as code with the rest of your app, then maybe not a problem. If not, be wary. A small performance gain may well not be worth the potential for lost developer time and shipping bugs.

Comment: in my case it's this opposite, all that's going on, except for this bit, is in the database, and yes the configuration file is stored with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently working somewhere that has gone all-in on SQL functions.. We have over a thousand.. I'd strongly advise against it.

Having logic split between Javascript and SQL is a real pain when debugging issues especially if, like me, you are much more familiar with JS.

The functions are at least all tracked in source control and get updated/created in the DB as part of the deployment process but this means you have 2 places to look at when trying to follow the code.

I fully agree with the other answer, single responsibility principle, DB for storage, server/app for logic.